# The benefits of using String.Empty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

I just don't understand the benefits of using String.Empty over "".  Aside it being strongly typed its longer.

So please, why should I be using this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Comment: -1 A quick search will reveal multiple duplicate questions on SO for the exact same topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been mentioned `string.Empty` creates no object where as `""` will create an object (albeit pulled out of the pool). The performance difference is minimal but the question should be what is more readable. I take the stance that `string.Empty` sticks out more than `""` and I can clearly see the intent of the declaration (string.Empty vs null). Regardless of your choice you should be consistent throughout your code base.

[String.Empty vs ""](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaningful difference. See these (and other) questions elsewhere on SO:
[In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or "" to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)
[Why is string.Empty more efficient than "" in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887430/why-is-string-empty-more-efficient-than-in-net)
[String.Empty versus ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905378/string-empty-versus-closed)
[What is the difference between String.Empty and “” and null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028170/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-and-null-closed)
[Which should I use for empty string and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192293/which-should-i-use-for-empty-string-and-why-closed)
[Difference between string.Empty and ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342358/difference-between-string-empty-and-closed)